# Gatsby 5 build error ( ERROR #11321 API.NODE.EXECUTION)

Tags: gatsby

I'm using GatsbyJS and Wordpress on my project. After updating Gatsby from v4 to latest v5 I can't build the project on the prod (gatsby build) and on dev. Also, after "gatsby clean" the first "gatsby develop" works fine, but the second one doesn't complete. Can somebody help my?

**"gatsby build" issue**

```
ERROR #85928  GRAPHQL.QUERY_RUNNING

An error occurred during parallel query running.
Go here for troubleshooting tips: https://gatsby.dev/pqr-feedback



  Error: Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpEnqueuedScriptConnectionType does not provide it.
  Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpEnqueuedStylesheetConnectionType does not provide it.
  Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpActionMonitorActionConnectionType does not provide it.
  Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpPluginConnectionType does not provide it.
  Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpThemeConnectionType does not provide it.
  
  - graphql-runner.ts:129 GraphQLRunner.validate
    [aristek-gatsby-website]/[gatsby]/src/query/graphql-runner.ts:129:22
  
  - graphql-runner.ts:218 GraphQLRunner.query
    [aristek-gatsby-website]/[gatsby]/src/query/graphql-runner.ts:218:49
  
  - query-runner.ts:140 queryRunner
    [aristek-gatsby-website]/[gatsby]/src/query/query-runner.ts:140:14
```

**"gatsby develop" issue**

```
ERROR #11321  API.NODE.EXECUTION

"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpEnqueuedScriptConnectionType does not provide it.

Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpEnqueuedStylesheetConnectionType does not provide it.

Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpActionMonitorActionConnectionType does not provide it.

Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpPluginConnectionType does not provide it.

Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpThemeConnectionType does not provide it.

  51 |
  52 | exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
> 53 |   await createBlogTags({ actions, graphql, reporter })
     |         ^
  54 |   await createBlogArchive({ actions, graphql, reporter })
  55 |   await createBlogArticle({ actions, graphql, reporter })
  56 |   await createArBlogArticle({ actions, graphql, reporter })

File: gatsby-node.js:53:9



  Error: Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpEnqueuedScriptConnectionType does not provide it.
  Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpEnqueuedStylesheetConnectionType does not provide it.
  Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpActionMonitorActionConnectionType does not provide it.
  Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpPluginConnectionType does not provide it.
  Interface field WpConnectionType.nodes expected but WpThemeConnectionType does not provide it.
  
  - graphql-runner.ts:129 GraphQLRunner.validate
    [aristek-gatsby-website]/[gatsby]/src/query/graphql-runner.ts:129:22
  
  - graphql-runner.ts:218 GraphQLRunner.query
    [aristek-gatsby-website]/[gatsby]/src/query/graphql-runner.ts:218:49
  
  - create-graphql-runner.ts:57 apply
    [aristek-gatsby-website]/[gatsby]/src/bootstrap/create-graphql-runner.ts:57:8
  
  - create-pages.ts:36 wrappedGraphQL
    [aristek-gatsby-website]/[gatsby]/src/services/create-pages.ts:36:47
  
  - createBlogTags.js:8 module.exports
    /Users/vilaribov/MyFiles/_webDev/aristek-gatsby-website/node/createBlogTags.js:8:24
  
  - gatsby-node.js:53 Object.exports.createPages
    /Users/vilaribov/MyFiles/_webDev/aristek-gatsby-website/gatsby-node.js:53:9
  
  - api-runner-node.js:487 runAPI
    [aristek-gatsby-website]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:487:37
  

failed createPages - 0.055s
```

**Packages**

```
"gatsby": "5.7.0",
  "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "5.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "3.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "5.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-no-index": "1.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "6.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "6.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "6.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "3.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "1.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-root-import": "2.0.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "5.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "6.7.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "5.7.0",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress": "7.7.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "5.7.0",
```

This [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/gatsbyjs/comments/wmm1eo/parallel_query_build_error/) doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was seeing a similar error. I downgraded WP Gatsby Wordpress plugin from v1.14 to v1.13.10 which seems to have allowed my build to work for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar situation. I suppose it is not **WP Gatsby** WordPress plugin meant but **WPGraphQL** WordPress plugin that needs to be downgraded to the version 1.13.10.